# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html - Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel-6

My application runs perfectly in localhost. Whereas it's not working in live server. In live server, I renamed the server.php to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from public directory to root directory. But following errors shows in console.

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

for all the css and javascript files.

here is the .htaccess file content in root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and here is the index.php in root directory.

```
$uri = urldecode(
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```